# Discord bot Javascript Declaration or statement expected

Tags: javascript, discord

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = "BEEP";
const PREFIX = "$$";

var bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("ready", function() {

  console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

  bot.user.setPresence({
    game: {
      name: "Choccy Milk",
      type: 0
    }
  });

});

bot.on("message", function(message) {
      if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

      if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");

        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
          case "ping":
            message.channel.send("Pong!");
            break;
        }

      });

    bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: Check your brackets, they're off near the end.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Final code is at the bottom of the answers, since there is a lot I needed to say in between.

**NOTE:** If you are only worried about it working, are not overly concerned with using good practice, OR do not like something I changed in order to use good practice: stop after step four.

There's a few things wrong with this code that must be fixed in order to get your bot to work properly. The first thing is the indentation. What you sent is extremely hard to read so if we modify it a bit we can easily identify the error. Here is your code with proper indentation.

**Step One: Indentation:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  var bot = new Discord.Client();

  bot.on("ready", function() {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  bot.on("message", function(message) {
     if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");

        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }

  });
```

Now isn't that way easier to read. You may already see the error. There is something missing on the second to last line. If there isn't any sort of red underline near the end of your code, I would download a new text-editor. Some of the most popular editors that can do this include VSCode, Atom, and Sublime Text. Links include https://code.visualstudio.com/ & https://atom.io/ & http://www.sublimetext.com/ (I prefer VSCode).

If you look closly, there is an IF block that is never fully closed. You would close it simply by adding another curly brace on the second to last line.

**Step Two: Syntax Correction:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  var bot = new Discord.Client();

  bot.on("ready", function() {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  bot.on("message", function(message) {
     if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");

        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });
```

At this point you will notice that your program works perfectly with no errors. The only problem is that your bot doesn't ever actually come on, this is because you never tell it to connect to Discord. You can never think that it will just assume the obvious. The reason why your program then closes is because you were just defining the actions but never running them. Thankfully Discord.JS does most of this work for you so all you need to do is type one line of code.

**Step Three: Connecting:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  var bot = new Discord.Client();

  bot.on("ready", function() {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  bot.on("message", function(message) {
     if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");

        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Well, that was easy. Now your bot will come online with the correct game. Just like you specified, if you type hello "hello", it will respond with "Hi, how are you!". This is great but if you type $$ping, literally nothing happens. This is because it only looks for the message $$ping if the message is also "hello". Obviously this is problematic because a message can't say two things at once. What we really want is for it to look for $$ping if the message isn't "hello". You can do this with an ELSE clause.

**Step Four: ELSE Clause:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  var bot = new Discord.Client();

  bot.on("ready", function() {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  bot.on("message", function(message) {
     if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  bot.login(TOKEN);
```

All I did was add one new line (line 22) with and "} else {". Now everything works perfectly but there are still a few problems that should be fixed. If there is something I do here that you do not like, just copy and paste the code from step four.

The first thing I recommend changing is the variable names; Specifically the name of the bot. As you probably notice, the method.Client() starts with an upper case letter. This was not an accident and was very correct on the developers parts. This is done when the method is a class or follows a specific object creation pattern. (The main OCP include factory, constructor and prototype). You can tell that it is one of these things because it requires the new keyword. After looking at the code of Discord.JS, I believe that it is a class. The way to fix this is to change that variable name to "Bot" from "bot" as well as all uses of the variable.

**Step Five: Variable Names**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  var Bot = new Discord.Client();

  Bot.on("ready", function() {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     Bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  Bot.on("message", function(message) {
     if (message.author.equals(Bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  Bot.login(TOKEN);
```

The next thing that should be changed is the Bot variable type. Normally, you want the  variable to be a constant. This is because if the variable changes, you do not want it to keep running; instead you want it to stop and tell you about the error and when it happened. This may become very important for if you ever and an eval command to your bot.

**Step Six: Constant Variable:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const Bot = new Discord.Client();

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  Bot.on("ready", function() {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     Bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  Bot.on("message", function(message) {
     if (message.author.equals(Bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  Bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Another problem with this code is that it uses the older form of functions. It is a standard in ECMAScript (AKA JavaScript) to use what is known as arrow functions. I'm honestly not sure why it is a standard instead of just a preference but it is so it is best for us to just follow it. Arrow functions are also better because they are more readable and do not have a local scope of the this keyword (an advantage because then you still have access to the global one). You use arrow functions by replacing function() { ... } with () => { ... } and if you want parameters, you can put them in the parenthesis just like a function. e.g (function(req, res, next) { ... } to (req, res, next) => { ... } ). Also if there is only one parameter, you don't even need the parenthesis. e.g (function(message) { ... } to message => { ... }). You can read up on the standards for ECMAScript and arrow functions here: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#arrows.

**Step Seven: Arrow Functions:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const Bot = new Discord.Client();

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  Bot.on("ready", () => {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     Bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  Bot.on("message", message => {
     if (message.author.equals(Bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  Bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Another adjustment that should be made is replacing the "var" keyword with "let". This is another one of those things where it has become a standard despite some people just preferring "var". The "let" keyword is better because it causes your code to run slightly faster, it's scoping is block-level, rather than function level which is a way more consistent way of doing it. The let keyword is also great because it allows you to temporary override variables in things like IF statements. Personally, I have fixed errors in my code by using let, probably because variables of a lower scope do not clash with ones of a higher scope. You can read up about the "let" keyword at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let. To make this change just replace the word "var" with "let". (There may be other steps needed for other pieces of code which is why I recommend reading up on let). You can see this extra step being done in the following example:

```
  (() => {

  var regex = /^[1-9]/u;
  var DateNow = Date.now();
  var token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;

  var condition1 = regex.test(String(token));
  var condition2 = DateNow > 1515354893761;

  if((condition1) && (condition2)) {
     var text = 'Yes';
  }else {
     var text = 'No';
  }

  console.log(text);

  })();
```

This would work perfectly but if I try to use "let", it does something very unexpected.

```
  (() => {

  let regex = /^[1-9]/u;
  let DateNow = Date.now();
  let token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;

  let condition1 = regex.test(String(token));
  let condition2 = DateNow > 1515354893761;

  if((condition1) && (condition2)) {
     let text = 'Yes';
  }else {
     let text = 'No';
  }

  console.log(text);

  })();
```

This does not work, but rather gives the error "ReferenceError: text is not defined". To fix this and still use "let", we just have to move it to a higher scope.

```
  (() => {

  let regex = /^[1-9]/u;
  let DateNow = Date.now();
  let token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;

  let condition1 = regex.test(String(token));
  let condition2 = DateNow > 1515354893761;

  let text;

  if((condition1) && (condition2)) {
     text = 'Yes';
  }else {
     text = 'No';
  }

  console.log(text);

  })();
```

This works exactly the same as the example with "var" while still being able to keep the "let" keyword. Another way we can do this is with the ternary operator.

```
  (() => {

  let regex = /^[1-9]/u;
  let DateNow = Date.now();
  let token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;

  let condition1 = regex.test(String(token));
  let condition2 = DateNow > 1515354893761;

  let text = (condition1) && (condition2) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

  console.log(text);

  })();
```

A ternary is a quicker way to do it but there is no ternary for other block types like loops.

Now lets get back to the code.

**Step Eight: LET Keyword:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const Bot = new Discord.Client();

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  Bot.on("ready", () => {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     Bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  Bot.on("message", message => {
     if (message.author.equals(Bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content == "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  Bot.login(TOKEN);
```

You probably want to use the triple equals operator in every situation possible. While it can't have much on this example it is a good habit to get into. The difference between double and triple equals is that double equals changes the datatypes of one side so that they match. While this may seem useful in practice it is better to convert them yourself when need to stop potential errors. This can be a mess when dealing with odd conversions, such as booleans. To get a full presentation of these errors, I would recommend **JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts - The First 3.5 Hours** on YouTube.

**Step Nine: Triple Equals:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const Bot = new Discord.Client();

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  Bot.on("ready", () => {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     Bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  Bot.on("message", message => {
     if (message.author.equals(Bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content === "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  Bot.login(TOKEN);
```

In Node.JS, you often want to make your functions asynchronous. This will not effect the current code but I thought it would be a good detail to add. You make an asynchronous function by adding an "async" keyword before your functions. Normally this does not matter but since Discord.JS is promise based, it is very good practice. You can read up on async and await here: https://javascript.info/async-await.

**Asynchronous Functions:**

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const Bot = new Discord.Client();

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  Bot.on("ready", async () => {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     Bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  Bot.on("message", async message => {
     if (message.author.equals(Bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content === "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  Bot.login(TOKEN);
```

I'm not going to show you how to do this part because it involves a lot of personal preference on how you want to handle your code in the future. I would recommend you modify your command system in a few ways:

- Make the command a separate variable from the arguments. You may want to look into the Array.slice() method for this.
- Make the command case-insensitive. You may want to look into the String.toLowerCase() method for this.
- Put the code for your commands in different files. You may want to look into the module.exports property for this.

If you are unsure on how to do anything in this list, tell me and I'll gladly help you out.

Judging by the simplicity of your code, it appears you are a beginner to Discord.JS. I would recommend you read through the documentation which can be found under: https://discord.js.org/#/ > Documentation.

Remember to change the token variable back to your bot's token.

---

### Final Code

```
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  const Bot = new Discord.Client();

  const TOKEN = "BEEP";
  const PREFIX = "$$";

  Bot.on("ready", async () => {
     console.log("ThunderBird is a go");

     Bot.user.setPresence({game: {
        name: "Choccy Milk",
        type: 0
     }});
  });

  Bot.on("message", async message => {
     if (message.author.equals(Bot.user)) return;
     if (message.content === "hello") {
        message.channel.send("Hi, how are you!");
     } else {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
           case "ping":
              message.channel.send("Pong!");
              break;
        }
     }
  });

  Bot.login(TOKEN);
```

**EDIT:** I just realized that you did put the bot.login. Sorry about that.